# Getting first element of a JSON Array with Alamofire/SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have an Alamofire request, which gives me JSON as a result. Here is my JSON:

```
"user" : {
    "field_first_name" : {
      "und" : [
        {
          "value" : "Christopher",
          "format" : null,
          "safe_value" : "Christopher"
        }
     ]
    },
```

The "und" value is an array, which usually only has one value in it. I'd like to grab the first element of this array at all times, as occasionally this field will have multiple elements, but the first is always the correct result.

The code below works, until I get to the ".first". This returns a value of type (String, JSON) and I cannot figure out how to get this item "firstValue" back into usable format. Whenever I try to use

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:parameters, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in

            if let data = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(json: data)


                let firstValue = json["user"]["field_first_name"]["und"].first
                print(firstValue!)
            }
        }
```

firstValue then becomes of type (String, JSON) and I have no idea how to handle this. What I'd like to get is the value for key "value" out of "firstValue.

This is what "firstValue" prints out:

```
("0", {
    "safe_value" : "Christopher",
    "value" : "Christopher",
    "format" : null
})
```

Is this approach salvageable? I could do a for in loop, get the first result, and tell it to ignore the rest, but that doesn't seem right. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40667425/parsing-json-data-from-alamofire-into-array-with-dictionary), instead of using first use array and then first and let me know if it works

Comment: I found a solution to this: firstValue is a tuple, of type (String, JSON), and I only need the second part of the tuple. So, if I do print(firstValue.1["value"]) it works

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to do something like this

```
   if let firstValue = json["user"]["field_first_name"]["und"].first?.1 {
      print(firstValue)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is over a year late, but this should work with your particular data. It's quite a long line of code though. I would break it up to make it more readable.

```
if let firstValue = json["user"]["field_first_name"] ["und"].arrayValue[0]["value"].string {
    print(firstValue)
{
```